# Have text align with black and white filter

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: text]

I have a background with a container that has a filter in its css that gives the lower half of the page a black & white effect.

What I want to do is have the lower half of the text do the same.Any ideas?

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="portfoliobackground">
        <NavbarInstance />
            <div className='headline'>Text here</div>
            <div className='profile-box container'>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is the css below

```
body{
  background: url('../images/wtc2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


.headline{
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans Expanded', sans-serif;
  color: #e22422;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 7.5em;
}


.profile-box{
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('../images/wtc.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 filter: grayscale(100%);
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 margin-top: 20%;

 border-top: white solid 3px;
 position: absolute;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

and

```
clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 0, 0 0);
```

respectively on two text elements ontop of each other with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to achieve this effect.

The first two that come to my mind are the following: both involve creating two different copies of the text (one that is colored, and the other one that is black or white). These two copies are placed one above the other using a fixed positioning and the z-index property (think of them as different layers).

### **OVERFLOW HIDDEN - IF YOU KNOW THE HEIGHT OF THE TEXT DIV**

In this case, you wrap the colored text in two containers:

1) The first one has a fixed height (in my example, 54px).

```
 #co_1{height:54px;}
```

2) The second has its height set to 50% of the parent, and its overflow is hidden (meaning that everything that goes beyond its borders is not displayed.

```
#co_2{height:50%;overflow:hidden;}
```

The black text, on the other hand, is fully displayed. Given that it is positioned *behind* the colored one, however, its upper half cannot be seen.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h88rr2kb/)

---

### **CLIP PATH - IF YOU DON'T KNOW THE HEIGHT OF THE TEXT DIV**

In this case, you use the clip-path CSS property to display two halves of the text: the upper case is colored, the bottom wrap the colored text in two containers.

This is the colored text (only the top half is displayed):

```
#co_1{clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 0, 0 0);}
```

And this is the black or white text (only the bottom half is displayed):

```
#co_2{clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);}
```

Please note that the clip-path property may not be fully supported [(see here)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)!

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftxr244/)